# DecimalFormat for input text inside the seekbar

Tags: android, decimalformat

I have a seek bar and inside of it I have some kind of calculation.

Ever thing is ok I can get the result in decimalformat but the problem is my input text

here is the seek bar code:

```
        .setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        int progressChanged = 0;
        // price to get
        final TextView PriceToGet = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.PriceToGet);
        // price to pay
        final TextView PriceToPay = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.PriceToPay);

        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar,
                int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            progressChanged = progress;
            TextView label = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.InputPercentSeek);
            label.setText("" + progressChanged);

            try {
                double price = Double.parseDouble(InputPrice
                        .getText().toString());
                double percent = Double.parseDouble(InputPercent
                        .getText().toString());

                double priceValue = price * percent / 100.0f;
                double percentValue = price - priceValue;

                PriceToGet.setText(String.valueOf(priceValue));
                PriceToPay.setText(String.valueOf(percentValue));

                PriceToGet.setText(df.format(priceValue));
                PriceToPay.setText(df.format(percentValue));

            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                // write a message to users
                InputPrice.setText("");
            }
```

I can't get my Input Text in decimal format!!

This is my Input

```
        InputPrice = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.InputPrice);
```

Appreciate any help

Thanks

Comment: post `LogCat` if you have any error.

Comment: I don't have any error... I can get the RESULTS perfectly in decimalformat the problem is I don't know how to use the decimalfromat for my input text!! I tried to do it the same as PriceToGet and PriceToPay but when I move the seekbar the number inside the INPUTTEXT will change and goes wrong.

Comment: You should mention what output you are expecting and what output you are getting.

Comment: Your question is not clear: what are you getting and what do you want?

Comment: Let say that this is my input : 88888 and here is my results 123,444.00. There is no problem with the result. I just want to show the input like 88,888. That is all the story.

Comment: I tried this code....      InputPrice.setText(df.format(price));
     The problem is when I move the seekbar the number disappear.